# Why didn't they use the passive form in the following sentence?

Tags: transitivity, passive-voice

I was studying the past continuous in "Grammar in Use, Cambridge University Press" and I saw a sentence that is strange for me:

I was doing something: I was in the middle of doing something at a certain time. **The action or situation had already started before this time, but had not finished.**

Why didn't they say "**The action or situation had already been started before this time, but had not been finished**"?

Comment: Because the action can itself start and finish; it does not have to "be started" and "be finished" by an external agent. P.S.  **start** and **finish** can be used both transitively and intransitively.

Comment: Your question is actually about transitive versus intransitive verbs.  The verbs "start" and "finish" can be used both transitively and intransitively for almost exactly the same meaning.  The only difference between the two is the implication.  In the first example (where "started" is intransitive), no indication about who or what caused the starting (or even if there was a cause) is given. In the second, it is implied that the "starting" was done by something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [start](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/start) and [finish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/finish) can be intransitive or transitive

> The party will start at 8pm - intransitive
>
> John will start school in September - transitive
>
> The party finished after midnight - intransitive
>
> John finished his drink and left - transitive

Note that what is starting or finishing moves from object to subject when you switch from intransitive to transitive.

It is perfectly ok to say "the action started..." or "the action finished".

Comment: A few minutes ago I was searching and I found something about intransitive and transitive verbs, but I was in doubt, but now I can understand... Thank you very much.